# Installing Keyboard Extension changes the iOS system language to Corsican based on bundle ID CFBundleIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-extensions, ios-keyboard-extension

I have built an iOS keyboard extension, before it is installed the system prefered language is "English" like so:

[image]

After installing the keyboard extension the system language is set to "Corsican", like so:

[image]

Corsican is being set because some of the bundle identifiers (`CFBundleIdentifier`) start with `co.<redacted>` which maps to the ISO 639-1 language code for Corsican `co`. I've verified that my `PrimaryLanguage` is `en-US`, see below a section of `Info.Plist`. I've verified the bundle ID is the root cause by changing the bundle ID to something not starting with `co` and this behaviour disappears.

```xml
<key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>IsASCIICapable</key>
            <false/>
            <key>PrefersRightToLeft</key>
            <false/>
            <key>PrimaryLanguage</key>
            <string>en-US</string>
            <key>RequestsOpenAccess</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.keyboard-service</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).KeyboardViewController</string>
    </dict>
```

This seems like a bug in iOS. Any suggestions what to try?